# List value in array with angularjs markup?

Tags: angularjs

I have this html :

```
<div class="{{ article.contributor }}" ng-repeat="article in articles">
```

Which gave me this :

```
<div class="["harry", "eddy", "john"]">
```

But I want this :

```
<div class="harry eddy john">
```

What is the best way to do this ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Do `<div ng-class="article.contributor" ng-repeat="article in articles">`

Comment: Sorry but this nos working, this give me `<div ng-class="article.contributor">`

Answer (score 0):

Try joining the array, like this:

```
<div class="{{ article.contributor.join(' ') }}" ng-repeat="article in articles">
```

Comment: If you don't check if it is an array and the server returns a string then this will break... no .join method on a string.

Comment: I agree, but that should be treated elsewhere, the question does not say from where the data comes, so I guess it´s safe to consider it to be always an array, even an empty one. Your answer is more detailed, the quick and dirty one is mine lol

Answer (score 0):

Ohhh the choices... joyous choices.
Quick and *dirty*...

`<div class="{{ typeof article.contributors === 'array' ? article.contributors.join(' ') : article.contributors }}" ng-repeat="article in articles"></div>`

As a filter...

```
myAppname.module.filter('spaceSeperatedValues', function() {
    return function(data){
        //handles if just a string (e.g., 'John')
        return data === 'array' ? data.join(' ') : data;
    }
}

<div class="{{ article.contributors | spaceSeperatedValues }}" ng-repeat="article in articles"></div>
```

As a controller function..

```
app.module.controller('ArticleController', ['$scope'], function ($scope) {
    $scope.articles = [{ text : 'my article text', contributors : ['harry', 'eddy', 'john'] }]

    $scope.spaceSeperatedValues = function(data) {
        //handles if just a string (e.g., 'John')
        return data === 'array' ? data.join(' ') : data;
    }
}


<div ng-controller="ArticleController">
    <div class="{{ spaceSeperatedValues(article.contributors) }}" ng-repeat="article in articles"></div>
</div>
```

Have not checked this code in a debugger... <-- disclaimer. :D